# Manipulate rows automatically before the `INSERT` statement

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm looking for a way to manipulate rows automatically before adding them to a table in postgreSQL. Say for instance we have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  value integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "Foo_value_check" CHECK (value >= 0)
)
```

Now one can insert rows:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id,value) VALUES ('0','2')
```

And when one enters:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id,value) VALUES ('1','-2')
```

An error will occur. Is it possible to define a "*rewrite rule*" that given the `value` column contains a value less than zero, zero is used (for instance)?

Comment: Unrelated but: don't use character literals for numbers. `'1'` is a character literal, `1` is a number. Using the wrong datatype literal can lead to problems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually, strangely enough it's OK for un-typed literals. `'1.0001'` is almost exactly the same as `1.0001` in the context of an un-typed literal; the only difference is that Pg will infer a default type if it isn't quoted and there's ambiguity. `'1'` isn't a character literal, it's an unknown-typed quoted literal that *might* be resolved as a character literal. There's no implicit cast happening from text here. After all, `'2001-01-01'` isn't a character literal and you don't have to explicitly write `DATE '2001-01-01'`.

Comment: @CraigRinger: even if it works: relying on implicit data type conversion is a bad habit (and many people have experienced that when upgrading from Postgres 8.3 to 8.4)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If this was implicit type conversion I'd agree with you, but *it isn't*. Take a look at the parser and early planner's source code - focus on handling of `unknown`-typed literals. The potential problem here is relying on type *inference* in contexts where ambiguity could appear later, e.g. function calls with overloads. Ambiguity is not possible for a simple `insert` into columns of known type. That is safe, and fine. Really. Quoting is unnecessary here, but harmless.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... and even if you don't quote, arbirary type selection or ambiguity is possible, e.g. is the litral `1.00001` typed `numeric` or `float4` or `float8`? (Answer: depends on context, but arbitrarily resolved as `numeric` if ambiguous).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... also, it's legal SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. One way is to use triggers. A trigger causes a procedure to be run on particular actions, which can allow you to modify the data to be inserted (amongst other things).

To set up a trigger, you first create a function that will perform the checks and modifications you want. The variable `new` in your function will be implicitly declared and contain the new row to be inserted / updated so you can check and modify the values before they reach the table.

You then specify that this function is to be called before insert or update on one or more tables.

Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION validate_foo_row()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF new.value<0 THEN
     new.value=0;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER trig_validate_foo BEFORE INSERT ON foo 
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE validate_foo_row();
```

[SqlFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/67ff74/1)

The above simplistic example only triggers for inserts, you might want to have it trigger for updates as well.

You can read more about triggers [in the postgresql manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html). They are powerful and are capable of a lot more than this simple example shows.